# How can I use facebook login with Create-react-native-app

Tags: facebook-login, create-react-native-app

I try to find a way to use Facebook login with Create-react-native-app for both Android and IOS. Is that possible? All this seem pretty new...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the [Expo SDK](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/facebook.html). This way you won't have to eject from create-react-native-app.

```
import { Facebook } from 'expo';

async function logIn() {
  const { type, token } = await Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync('<APP_ID>', {
    permissions: ['public_profile'],
  });

  if (type === 'success') {
    // Get the user's name using Facebook's Graph API
    const response = await fetch(`https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=${token}`);

    Alert.alert(
      'Logged in!',
      `Hi ${(await response.json()).name}!`,
    );
  }
}
```

Snippet taken from the link.

Comment: I have to say, I'm clueless as to why people downvoted your question... It is very legitimate. They either misread it or have no clue what create-react-native-app is.

Comment: Haha Thanks for your support :) I place my bet on the second ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try using other library like [react-native-fbsdk](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk) or [react-native-facebook-login](https://github.com/magus/react-native-facebook-login). You can read the documentation because there is an example how to implement login with facebook.

Answer (score -1):

User https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk library.

Tyler wrote a detailed blog on how to install the Facebook SDK into a React Native Android or iOS App.  https://tylermcginnis.com/installing-the-facebook-sdk-into-a-react-native-android-and-ios-app/

You can go through them and implement Facebook login into React Native app.